# Show data from Entity Framework into DataGridView

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want show data from Entity Framework into DataGridView in C# WinForm. Data in DataGridView can change and update to sql database.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick search for this on Google and you can find many examples:

1) [Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18503956/populating-a-programatically-declared-datagridview-using-datasource-and-entity-f)

2) [Example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12501183/data-binding-linq-query-to-datagridview-in-entity-framework-5-0)

3) [Example 3](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj682076.aspx)

You can see a simple example here:

```
Context db = new Context();
var data = (from d in db.tablename select d);
dataGridView1.DataSource = data.ToList();
```

Ideally you should move the database call into a separate method, which is in a business class library or something similar. But for the purposes of keeping this example simple, I'll leave you to figure that out.

With regards to updating data in the grid you can [search this on Google](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=update%20data%20in%20datagridview%20c%23) and find many results and detailed tutorials.

Comment: Thanks for Answer
My query is:

var query = (from ed in db_context.Ratings
                         join sp in db_context.Students on ed.StudentID equals sp.IdStudent
                         where ed.ExamDisciplineID == edis.IdExamDiscipline
                         select new { sp.IdStudent, sp.Fullname, ed.Rating1, ed.Rating2 }
                    ).Distinct().ToList();

            dataGridView1.DataSource = query;

I want to change Rating1, Rating2 and in change update to data table. But this Colunms are Read Only